# Input Problem with Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to do a programming exercise here making a client and a server that work with sockets.For the communication between them i use PrintWriter and InputReader.What im stuck with is : How can i check if the Server is trying to send something to the client,while the client is waiting for input ? At this point the client loop is something like this :

```
do {
                outToServer.println(inFromUser.readLine());
                String fromServer=inFromServer.readLine();
                if(fromServer.equals("OK")){
                    clientSocket.close();
                }else{
                    System.out.println(fromServer);
                }
            } while (!clientSocket.isClosed());
```

The problem is that in some cases the server needs to print multiple lines ,before needed  an input again.Instead it prints 1 line then ill have to type something,then another line comes etc . Is there a way to get around that problem ? Thanks .

Comment: What are you trying to create? Is you goal is to make a chat application?

Comment: No its just a simple exercise were you send commands to a server and it does things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're going to need to encapsulate the

```
outToServer.readLine();
```

in a while loop that has a boolean conditional similar to a hasNext() function. You may want to set it up as follows:

```
String x = outToServer.readLine();
//while x doesn't equal whatever readLine would return if there's nothing to read
//I'm not sure if this is a null String or not
while(x!=null){
    System.out.print(x);//print it however you wish
    String x = outToServer.readLine();
}
```

And then do something similar for inFromServer if needed.

Comment: Let me know if this helped or not.

Comment: If you're using a BufferedReader, the end of the stream returns a null String, so the above conditional should be correct. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

Comment: The problem is still there since when i call readLine() the program will wait till i write something .I tried to solve that with .ready() which is supposed to return true if i have written something(or thats what i understood) but it didnt work.

Comment: So when you call readLine(), the program waits till you write something? Is that due to your code or the specific class of Reader you're using? What class of Reader are you using specifically? BufferedReader?

Comment: Yes >BufferedReader inFromUser =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
i read that it waits for input when i call .readLine() .

Comment: So it seems like you changed your code. Now you're printing what must be inputed from the user in: "outToServer.println(inFromUser.readLine());"

So what's happening in reality is that you're just going through the do-while loop again. So are you encapsulating all of:

    "String fromServer=inFromServer.readLine();
    if(fromServer.equals("OK")){
        clientSocket.close();
    }else{
        System.out.println(fromServer);
    }"

In the kind of loop I described in my answer? Because, if not, that would cause the do-while loop to continue.

Comment: I see that you've marked this as the answer. Did it solve your problem? Why wasn't it working before? Was it because of what I said in the earlier comment? I'm asking because I'll likely be working a lot with sockets in a month or so, and I'm curious.

Comment: Actually no i found a different way to solve it using a client i found somewere else. I just didnt want people to keep bothering since i didnt need answer anymore so i marked it . Thanks tho.

Comment: Ah ok. Haha you could have just answered it yourself. :-) Which client did you use?

Comment: Its not an actual client. Its something that you can use on osx from terminal not sure about windows. you type in : telnet hostname portnumber and it connects to the server . Like telnet localhost 4340.